# How to use noindex, follow on duplicate pages for search engines

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, seo, layout-update, canonical

I can easily set `NO INDEX, FOLLOW` on particular page through layout update.

But what I want is, I need to set `NO INDEX, FOLLOW` when the page loads after filtering from layered navigation on product listing page.

For Eg : `https://test.com/recording-studio/keyboard-controllers.html?number_of_keys=37&price=-150`

This is duplicate of `https://test.com/recording-studio/keyboard-controllers.html`. So need not to be indexed.

Any solutions for this ?

Comment: you should also consider configuring the number_of_keys query string in google console (formerly webmaster tools) so that google knows how this query affects the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to accomplish this. First of all, you can use canonical URLs. This will tell the search engines that, although they are on a different URL, the canonical URL is the actual URL of the current page. This can be done within Magento by going to **System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog** and then set the options **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories** and **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products** under the tab **Search Engine Optimisation** to "Yes".

Second of all, you can define this in your robots.txt, which you can place in your project's root folder. This will not add a "noindex, nofollow" tag to your page, but it will tell search engines to ignore those pages.

An example of the robots.txt that I always use [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/ArjenMiedema/a50d77d6aae69ffbc4b4dbf993c3a51e).

Of course you could also add a meta tag in your page, but that won't work for specific parameters (?price=xxx, etc.). For that you could [use this page (also shared by Arunendra)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149936/4155637).

Comment: Could you elaborate at all on some of the things included in that robots.txt and why it would be recommended for a Magento 2 site from an SEO perspective?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore dynamic urls using robots.txt just you need to add this line in this file you can find this file on your root folder:

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

[For more see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149936/4155637)

Comment: I added `Disallow: /*?*` on robots.txt and cleared cache. run cron manually And again viewed the page with such parameters. Still no any changes

Comment: I would not suggest using this, because this will also disallow search engines to view/index the pagination of your category. So it will only index the first page (without `?p=x) and will also only not index the URLs for the products on these pages.

Comment: @sagarsapkota it will affect on search engine not on your website, it will disallow indexing from search engine please read about robots.txt

Comment: @ArjenMiedema why you want to index the category pagination ?? read here for more info https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?csw=1

Comment: @Arunendra there is a difference between indexing and crawling. I want search engines to follow the links, so it can index the products on those pages. I don't want it to index the other pages in the pagination. That's why you should also enable the canonical URL.